# how to set dropdownlist control to column in modal popup of jq grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with add and Edit modal popup, I want to set for a column value as dropdownlist control which have different values to select, is it possible to set like that, or is there any have alternate solution.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it with javascript using  function

```
         colModel: 
         { name: 'Ename', index: 'Ename', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: 'select', align: 'center', formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: getAllSelectOptions() } 

         function getAllSelectOptions() {
        var states = {
            '1': 'Alabama', '2': 'California', '3': 'Florida',
            '4': 'Hawaii', '5': 'London', '6': 'Oxford'
        };

        return states;
        }
```